# Connection between apache2 server and client breaks after 6 minutes

Tags: php, symfony, apache2

I've got big issue with connection between user browser and apache2 server. We've to process a lot of data, so the request takes more time, and client have to wait for response more than few minutes. It worked well for a month.. then it started breaking the connection (or something similar).

Every time connection is closed after 6 minutes. Chrome browser throws an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. DHC shows `No response` and `No content`. In apache `error.log`, log level set to debug, there's nothing, running `tail -f dev.log` in symfony I can see, that script is still running.. till the end, no errors.

Weird is that when I run the script from Windows the connection is lossed not after 6 minutes but 12. I've got 12 minutes when I run 2 different requests by browser on Mac.

2 days of debugging and nothing. Not even a single row of log.

Where can I look next? Network logs? Maybe someone had same issue?

Comment: Your script is not meant to be launched in a browser. You should use a command.

Comment: I know, it will be optimized and build on RabbitMQ. But now we've no time to do it. That cannot be a command service, final user have to run it. It worked well for even 2 hours requests. Now it can't handle 6 minutes.

Comment: No time ? Transfering a script / controller to a command is a matter of 5 minutes. http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html Moreover using a command will allow you to add debug messages, monitor memory, etc.

Comment: As i said, this is and have to be a component of user interface. For now it don't matter that i run a command or request, because script is running well this way too, but connection breaks and user dont know if the process is done.

I can tell the user if its done and I will till it will be optimized, thats not a big issue, but i would like to know what cause this problem...

Comment: Yes it's a matter because you would not have the problem with a command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find reason, but the answer is streamed response + JSON. Connection won't break if there's a response.

This gave powerful tool for debug (live memory usage) and showed me that the problem is memory (Enity Manager in doctrine is very low when it stores too much objects).

Btw, cool way to work with Doctrine's `$em->clear()`.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $item = $this->em->getReference('AppBundle:Item',$item->getId());
    .......

    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();
}
```

That's cool, because you don't need to detach objects related to `$item`, just full clear and attach it back. Works really fast.